# jQuery UI datepiker not attached to input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I added a [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) datepiker [here](http://rb-dev.eximo.net/search). You could see it on the left side of the page under *Date Available*.

I can't make it fixed on the input textbox. If you scroll or re-size, the calendar window is floating around the screen. I need it remain on the default open position when scrolling and resizing. I tried all the possible fixes but no chance. How do I fix this problem?

I call it like:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are repositioning the `datepicker` container on `window` `scroll` event then consider the `document` `scroll` position also. I think that is what creating this issue.

Comment: Thank you , could you be please more specific? i just used the default datepiker just changed the css to match my color requirements

Comment: Do you have any code to reset the datepicker's position on page scroll?

Comment: Take a look here http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ it works fine. May be some css is screwing it up in your site.

Comment: i know there is ok .. i used this in other sites too without problems .. my question was how tomake the datepiker in this example stay fixed....

Comment: You are including `jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js` in your site. What is custom js?